# What is wrong with my minimal typeahead.js example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, typeahead.js

I've read all the official documentation, I've Googled, I've looked at the console there is no errors, but I can't get Twitter's typeahead.js to function at all.

I put up a test page [here](http://www.muschamp.ca/Muskie/lookaheadTest.html).

My actual source is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Lookahead Test</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 9.6" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src='http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.css' />
    </head>
<body>
<h1>This is a test of Twitter's typeahead.js</h1>
<div>
<form>
<input id="departure" type="text" placeholder="This appears when you load page">
</form>
</div>
<script>
$('#departure').typeahead({                                
  name: 'departure',                                                          
  prefetch: '/test.json',                                         
  limit: 10                                                                   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I only put three lines in the JSON file, it looks like this:

```
[
    "Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada (YVR)",
    "Calgary, Alberta, Canada (YYJ)",
    "Toronto, Lester B. Pearson International Airport, Ontario, Canada (YYZ)"
]
```

I originally had curly braces, but fixing that didn't make it go. I've looked at several working examples and I keep making changes to mine, but it never has worked. Do I need at least 10 pieces of data in my JSON file? Is the stylesheet mandatory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the JSON file you are creating actually at the root of the site?

Comment: My coworker thought /test.json was wrong. I previously had ./test.json and tried his suggestion of test.json, no love. However I tried a full http://path.to/test.json and it worked. #Frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the incorrect path to my JSON file. I modified it to be absolute and that made the JavaScript go.